# Is there a way to display the binary contents of individual files in an O365 group drive via REST?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to see if there's a way to show the binary contents of a specific file in an O365 group drive via the REST API. Is there any way to do this? I'm trying to setup a file transfer via REST.

Comment: Do you just want to see the bytes listed in the browser, or do you want to do uploads and downloads? REST is typically not needed. Just write pretty standard code for C#, etc., to do HTTP uploads and downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for a REST download of a file: (the key is the "/$value" at the end.)

```
https://yourDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/yourSite/shared%20documents/AdventureWorksBikes.xlsx')/$value
```

This article shows REST uploads: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery

The URL looks something like this and is sent as a POST:

```
https://yourDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/sites/yourSite//shared documents/TestFolder')/files/add(overwrite=true, url='test.txt')
```

Header looks like this:

```
{"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
           "content-length":__len__,
           "X-RequestDigest": "__yourRequestDigest__"}
```

The body contains the bytes to upload.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Would this work the same for O365 groups as opposed to Sharepoint sites? I also wasn't sure if "/_api/ was accessible if I was going thru Microsoft Graph.

Comment: The "group" site you see when you click files is a SharePoint site.
URL to a group: https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?path=/group/testgroup@yourDomain/files
URL to the backing SP site: https://yourDomain/sites/testgroup